# Start process in Java which has password prompt

Tags: java, processbuilder, outputstream

I want to start a process that asks for a password. The password should be provided automatically. I tried:

```java
Process process = processBuilder.start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(os);
writer.write(new String(password) + "\n");
```

But the password is apparently not written to the process. The process instead waits forever until it is killed.

How can I answer password prompts from within Java?

Comment: I would read from `Process#getInputStream` and `Process#getErrorStream`, to ensure you're not hitting some weird error. For the hell of it, throw a `writer.flush()` after anyhow, even though there's a newline. Alternatively, use the `PrintWriter#print*` methods instead of `#write`.

Comment: Looks like the `writer.flush()` was what I was missing.